# Cardinal of a group $G$ such that for all $x\in G$ we have $x^2=e$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that for all $x\in G$ we have $x^2=e$. Show that if $G$ is finite then the order of $G$ is $2^n$.

Here is the solution I have seen in a book.

> If G is finite, it can be considered as a vector space over the field $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, and then necessarily is finite dimensional, which gives $G$ as a vector space isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^n$.

I don't understand why $G$ can be considered as a vector space over the field $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Can, someone, explain this? Please.

Comment: Perhaps a more straightforward proof: if $|G|$ is finite and is divisible by some prime $p \neq 2$, then by Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has an element $g$ of order $p$. But then $g^2 = e$ is a contradiction.

Comment: @Bungo Surely very interesting, unfortunately I do not know (yet?) Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show that $G$ is a vector space, first you must show that it is abelian. Assuming you have established this, then we can write the group operation additively, and if $g,h \in G$ then $g+h$ is the sum of the two "vectors" $g$ and $h$. The condition $g^2 = e$, translated into additive notation, becomes $g + g = 0$.

Now consider the field $F = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This field contains two elements, $0$ and $1$, with the property that $1+1 = 0$.

We define multiplication of a scalar $a\in F$ by a "vector" $g \in G$ in the obvious way: $ag = 0$ if $a = 0$, and $ag = g$ if $a = 1$.

Now we just need to verify the [vector space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition). The first four, namely associativity and commutativity of addition, existence of an additive identity, and existence of additive inverses, are consequences of the fact that $G$ is an abelian group.

The remaining four are simple to check:

1. If $a,b \in F$ and $g \in G$, then $a(bg)$ and $(ab)g$ are both zero if either $a=0$ or $b=0$, and they are both $g$ if $a=b=1$.
2. If $1$ is the multiplicative identity in $F$ and $g \in G$, then $1g = g$ by the way we defined multiplication of a scalar by a vector.
3. If $a \in F$ and $g,h \in G$, then $a(g+h)$ and $ag + ah$ are both zero if $a = 0$, and they are both $g+h$ if $a = 1$.
4. If $a,b \in F$ and $g \in G$, then $(a+b)g = 0$ if $a=b$ and $(a+b)g = g$ if $a \neq b$. This is because of the definition of addition in $F$. Likewise, $ag + bg = 0$ if $a=b$ (because of the condition $g+g = 0$), and $ag + bg = g$ if $a \neq b$ (because exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is zero and the other is one).

So the only remaining question is, what is the cardinality of $G$? Well, $G$ is finite dimensional, so it has some basis $\{g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n\}$. Since $F$ has two elements, the set of all possible linear combinations $a_1 g_1 + \ldots + a_n g_n$ (where each $a_i \in F$) has cardinality $2^n$.

---

For completeness, here is a proof that the condition $x^2 = e$ for all $x \in G$ forces $G$ to be abelian. If $x,y \in G$, then $xyxy = (xy)(xy) = e$. Therefore, multiplying on the left by $x^{-1}$ and on the right by $y^{-1}$, we get $yx = x^{-1}y^{-1}$. Therefore, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = xyyx = x(yy)x = xex = xx = e$. Multiplying $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = e$ on the right by $y$ and then by $x$ gives us $xy = yx$.

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative proof:**

We have $x=x^{-1}$ so

$$\forall x,y\in G,\quad xy=(xy)^{-1}=yx$$
so $G$ is abelian. If $G=\{e\}$ then $|G|=2^0$. If $G\ne \{e\}$ so let $G\ni g_1\ne e$ and  $H_1=\{e,g_1\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. If $G=H_1$ then $|G|=2^1$ and if not let $g_2\not\in H_1$ and then 
$$H_2=H_1\cup g_2H_1$$
is a subgroup of $G$ and has the order $2^2$. With this construction we see that by a finite induction the order of $G$ is $2^n$.

Comment: Thanks but you are not answering the question...

Answer (score 0):

Bungo has given a very detailed proof that such a $G$ is a vector over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. However, I'll give a slightly more abstract argument that makes the verification a little quicker.

For any ring $R$ (We'll consider commutative rings with unity), we can define the notion of an $R$-module $M$, which is basically a vector space except the scalars come from a ring. All the axioms are the same. However $R$-modules are not necessarily as nicely behaved if $R$ is not a field. One very important idea is that a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is simply an abelian group. the multiplication is simply

$$(n,x) \mapsto x^n$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in G$. This is the reason people tend to like writing Abelian groups with the binary operation as "vector addition". Hopefully you already see how much more complicated general $R$-modules are.

One way in which a module $M$ over $R$ can be "bad" is that we can define $$\text{Ann }M =  \{r \in R | rm = 0, \forall m \in M\}$$

This is an ideal of $R$, and for any ideal $I \subset \text{Ann } M$, the module $M$ has a natural structure as an $R/I$-module, by the rule $(r +I)m := rm$.

Finally an Abelian group $G$ such that $x^2 = e$ for all $x$ (additively written as $2x =0$) is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module with $\text{Ann }G = 2\mathbb{Z}$. So $G$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module, which since this is a field, is a vector space.

But honestly all this is a bit much. I would say the better argument for the exercise is to apply Cauchy's theorem, which said that for a prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ contains an element of order $p$. Since all nontrivial elements of $G$ have order $2$, $2$ is the only prime diving $|G|$.

Comment: There's another reason the proof via Cauchy's theorem is better: it allows for cases like "the order of every element is a power of $2$." and the generalization "every element is of order (a power of) $p$".